# Graph problem with drawing

Tags: graph-theory

How can I draw a disconnected graph with 25 vertices and every vertex has a degree of 12?
I know that the graph exists because the degree sum formula is equal to even, but if I draw a K13 graph it will always exclude one vertice.

Comment: The degree sum formula does not say that such a *disconnected* graph exists.

Comment: 25vertices x 12 degree each = 300 is even number so i thought it exits a graph

Comment: Graphs exist with 25 vertices all of degree 12, but why would there be one that is disconnected?

Comment: So does that mean vertices should be even for exist a disconnected graph?

Comment: Vertices having even or odd degree is completely unrelated to whether the graph is connected or disconnected.

Comment: Having a degree 12 means the vertex has 12 neighbors. Which makes 13 vertices in the connected component (or more). And you need a graph disconnected, hence at least _two_ connected components. Now two (or more) components, each with 13 (or more) vertices, make the total number of vertices at least.....?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
@JaapScherphuis has already actually hinted, but I will formulate this hint explicitly.
Just notice that any component of such graph must have at least $13$ vertices.